General version of the fundamental lemma of calculus of variations
Let the measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be a general Borel measure.
Let $f:\mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a locally integrable function and $\int f\varphi d\mu =0$ for any smooth function $\varphi $ with compact support.
Then, I want to show that $f=0, \mu$-a.e. holds.
I think that using topological regularity for measure $A\mapsto \int _{A} |f|$ and smooth version of Urysohn’s lemma would work, but I am not sure.

That strategy sounds good. You could also use the differentiation theorem.

Remark: Here, we are assuming that $\mu$ is locally finite, such that mollified functions convergence pointwise a.e. to the original function.
This is a standard argument, that can probably be found in many Functional Analysis books:
Set $A_r^+ := \lbrace f \geq 0 \rbrace \cap B_r(0)$ for any $r>0$ and approximate $\chi_{A_r^+}$ pointwise a.e. by $\varphi_\varepsilon *\chi_{A_r^+}$ where $\varphi_\varepsilon$ is a standard mollifier. Moreover, for $0 < \varepsilon < 1$, $\mathrm{supp}(\varphi_\varepsilon *\chi_{A_r^+}) \subseteq B_{r+1}(0)$. Hence, on $B_{r+1}(0)$
$$
\lvert (\varphi_\varepsilon *\chi_{A_r^+})f \rvert \leq \lvert f \rvert \in L^1(B_{r+1}(0))
$$
and
$$
0 = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} (\varphi_\varepsilon *\chi_{A_r^+})f = \int_{B_{r+1}(0)} (\varphi_\varepsilon *\chi_{A_r^+})f \overset{\varepsilon \searrow 0}{\longrightarrow} \int_{B_{r+1}(0)} \chi_{A_r^+}f = \int_{A_r^+} f.
$$
By monotone convergence you get $0 = \int_{A_r^+} f = \int_{B_r(0)} f^+ \overset{r \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f^+ $. Hence $f^+=0$ and similarly $f^- = 0$.

Thank you so much!

You're welcome. I just shot from the hip, so please correct me if there are errors.

If the convolution is the defined as a Lebesue intergral $\varphi\ast\chi(x)=\int\varphi(x-y)\chi(y)dy$ there is no relation with the given measure $\mu$. So, why should $\varphi_\varepsilon\ast\chi_{A_r^+}$ converge $\mu$-a.e.? I think that you need the measure $\mu$ to be locally finite so that one can use inner and outer regularity.

You are right that I assumed that $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure. (I did not read that we were talking about a general measure; I will modify the answer). And yes, if $\mu$ is regular and locally finite, the continuous functions with compact support are dense such that we still have $\varphi_\varepsilon * \chi_{A_r^+} \rightarrow \chi_{A_r^+}$ pointwise a.e.. Do you know whether the fundamental thm. of calc. of variations actually holds for non-regular measures? @Jochen

Locally finite Borel measures on $\mathbb R^n$ are automatically regular and for measures which are not locally finite (like $\mu(A)=$ cardinality of $A\cap \mathbb Q$) the integrals $\int \varphi d\mu$ (which should identify the measure with a distribution) are not even defined.

Thank you, I didn't know that
